# Adding Gmail account to Microsoft Outlook - can't connect to IMAP server

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am using Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO - 32-bit (16.0.11328.20468) on Windows 10, and I would like to access my Gmail account from within Outlook.

I know this is an "old question", and I have been reading different answers both here and elsewhere. 
Unfortunately, the most commonly suggested actions don't work for me.

What I did is to follow the instructions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081), including (1) preliminary setting the Gmail options to enable IMAP access for other clients, and (2) using the "App password" after enabling the 2-step verification as suggested [also here](https://support.office.com/fi-fi/article/j%C3%A4rjestelm%C3%A4ss%C3%A4-tapahtui-virhe-gmailin-lis%C3%A4%C3%A4misess%C3%A4-outlookiin-bc5403de-1e0f-4156-96a8-f7d084699dc1?ui=fi-FI&rs=fi-FI&ad=FI).

I keep getting the error "We couldn't connect to your IMAP server. 
Please check the IMAP server settings and try again."

Any ideas of what I should try to do?

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel, Mail, and add the Gmail Account this way. Be sure you select to select Manual Setup and do not use the Wizard. Then go through all the steps and you should be able to add a working Gmail Account.

Here are the two basic screens for clarity. Once you get into the Account screens you need the Gmail parameters but I think you know these.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The author wants to use Outlook not the Mail UWP application.  How does this accomplish the author's goal?  I am particularly interested since I have had some trouble getting Outlook to play nice with my own Google Mail accounts.

Comment: Yes. I use Outlook myself and the Control Panel method works best with Outlook 2016 (365)

Comment: I tried as suggested, but I am still not able to get it working. If it works for you, which settings do you use for IMAP and SMTP? I tried 993 SSL/TLS and 587 STARTTLS

Comment: @John Thanks for the clarification, that's what I did

Comment: I use 993 SSL/TLS and 587 STARTLS

Comment: Nothing... I also tried SSL: 465 for the outgoing

Comment: One thing you might try is to make a new Outlook Email profile.  Make sure any PST or OST file is backed up in a safe location. Make sure you know how to re-create all your accounts. Now in the Profiles button in Control Panel, Mail delete your Outlook Profile. Close out, restart, make a new Outlook Profile first, then make the Gmail Account as described above.

Comment: To confirm whether this is a client issue or a account issue, please try configuring another Gmail account to your Outlook client and see if there is any difference. If the issue can be reproduced, then you may try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the "Work Offline" button in Outlook's Send/Receive tab has been accidentally clicked.

Comment: And what if it has?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.